# Python executable bundled with pyinstaller doesn't work on some windows 10 computers

Tags: python-3.x, windows-10, wxpython, pyinstaller

I'm working on a wxPython 4 GUI application for Windows. I'm currently using python 3.7. On some Windows 10 computers it runs correctly but on others it returns immediately without showing any errors or sign of being executed.

When I build it without the --windowed flag it works just fine, but I don't want the console to show on production environment.

Here is the pyinstaller command I'm using:

```
pyinstaller -y -F -w -i "C:/workspace/iconesefundos/redepos.ico" -p ./wxfdl -p . "C:/workspace/frentedeloja/wxfdl/wxfdl.py"
```